# How to diagonalize this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the $n\times m$ matrix $M=[M_1, \ldots, M_m]$ where the $i$-th column reads

$$
M_i= \,^t(\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{a_i},0,\ldots,0)
$$
where the $a_i$'s are given positive natural numbers.

Is it possible to compute the  singular values of $M$ in terms of the $a_i$'s ?

Maybe it is simpler if one choose the $a_i$'s non-decreasing.

I am interested  in this problem since it somehow generalize the case where  $n=m$ and $a_i=n$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$, and for which the singular values are $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $n^2$ with multiplicity $1$. This comes from an easy kernel size plus trace argument. And I was wondering if it could be applied to this general case, but I didn't succeed ...

Comment: To start you're going to need $n = m$ to have eigenvalues or to talk about diagonalizing.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly, you allow some of the $a_{i}$ to be zero?

Comment: The rank of such a matrix can be found by inspection. Is that enough of a generalization of the all 1s case?

Comment: @polkjh Permutation changes eigenvalues. Otherwise the determinant is always preserved. Yet some permutation matrices have determinant -1.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for pointing that out. I removed that comment.

Comment: @Jim :  I meant singular values, typo corrected, thx.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti: let's say no.

Comment: @hardmath: Depending on the $a_i$'s, the rank could be anything between $0$ and $\min(n,m)$ ...

Comment: @Student: Of course all $m \times n$ matrices have ranks between $0$ and $\min \{m,n\}$.  I'm saying the rank for your particular class of matrices can be found "by inspection", namely by counting "leading ones", once the columns are sorted by length of 1s as you suggested.  In any case this gives the size of the nullspace for square matrices; as mentioned your notion of diagonalization and/or eigenvalues of nonsquare matrices is ambiguous at best.

Comment: @hardmath: I did correct my question replacing eigenvalues by singular values. There is nothing ambiguous speaking about the singular values of non-square matrices.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that edit!

Comment: Perhaps it's an artifact of the revised wording about singular values, but the "all-ones" matrix has a non-zero singular value of $n$, not $n^2$.

Comment: @hardmath: You're right ! Thx

Answer (score 2):

Since we are now asking about singular values, arranging the columns for *non-decreasing* $a_i$ is without loss of generality.  A permutation of columns does not affect a matrix's singular values.

Consider $A = M'M$, a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, whose eigenvalues are squares of the singular values of $M$.  $A$ is a structured matrix with $A_{ij} = \min \{a_i,a_j\} = a_{\min \{i,j\} }$.

The nonsingular case ($n \times n$ matrix, strictly increasing $a_i = i$) is included in a "test case gallery" as `minij` in [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html#f84-1000066) and other suites.  According to comments in [this test C code](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/test_mat/test_mat.c), the eigenvalues of $A$ have an explicit formula:

$$ \frac{0.5}{ 1 - \cos \left( \frac{( 2k - 1 )\pi}{ 2n + 1 } \right) } \;\; \forall \; 1 \le k \le n $$

Accordingly the singular values of $M$ should be the respective square roots of those.  For $n=2$ we get singular values $\varphi = 1.61803\ldots$ and $\varphi - 1 = 0.61803\ldots$ as a perhaps lucky connection to [the golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

A similarly simple expression for singular values of the singular cases seems a daunting challenge, if only because of the large number of possibilities.  However the rank of $M$ (resp. of $A$) can be found by counting the number of columns containing a "leading one", since removing duplicate rows puts $M$ in [row-echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) (due to column sorting).  Therefore the nullity (dimension of nullspace) of $M$ is easily found, or in other words the count of singular values which are zero.